# IPN vs Webhook | Checkout básico recibiendo desde v1/payments

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy implementando el checkout básico, y configurando mi IPN al crear la preferencia:

```
'notification_url' => <<mi url pública>>
```

Por post, estoy recibiendo una estructura como la que recibiría en el Checkout personalizado.
Probé con sandbox y con testusers.

Cuando hago un get_payment_info del id recibido, obviamente no encuentra el pago. También probé utilizando v1/payments/id (Tampoco lo encontré ahí, está bien ya que es un pago con checkout básico)

La estructura que me informa el IPN es la siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7452500
        )

    [date_created] => 2017-10-08T22:53:14.000-04:00
    [type] => payment
    [api_version] => v1
    [id] => 209604112
    [action] => payment.created
    [user_id] => 187315714
    [live_mode] => 
    [data_id] => 7452500
)
```

Comment: Buenas, te molestaría compartirme el código que tenés implementado para las IPN?, no logro que me acepte la url mercadopago. Me pide un status 200 o 201 que mi código si devuelve pero no sabría porque motivo mercadopago no me lo toma. Saludos!

Comment: el tema es que te mandan el request por post. Asegúrate de que no tire ninguna excepción